# How to use Faker library in a Playwright test suite?

Tags: typescript, playwright, faker.js

I have created a test file with different test blocks for testing a scenario and I want to use the Faker library for generating data.

I want to have a base email and password and use them in all test blocks, but for example, when I call the email variable in different `test` blocks, the value of the email variable will be changed.

Here is an example from my codebase:

```
const email = faker.internet.email();
const password = faker.internet.password();
const newPassword = faker.internet.password();
const simplePassword = faker.internet.password();

test.describe('Signup a new user', async ({ page }) => {
  test('Signup a new user', async ({page}) => {
    await SignUp.EnterEmail(email);
    await SignUp.EnterPassword(password);
  
  }
  
  test('Try to change password with a valid new password', async ({page}) => {
    await Profile.typeCurrentPassword(password) // value will change here
    await Profile.typeNewPassword(newPassword);
    await Profile.confirmPassword(newPassword
    await Profile.save();
  
  }
  
  test('// Try to change password with simple password', async ({page}) => {
  
    await Profile.typeCurrentPassword(password) // value will change here
    await Profile.typeNewPassword(simplePassword);
    await Profile.confirmPassword(simplePassword
    await Profile.save();
  
  }

}
```

The problem is when I use the `password` variable in each test block, the value of the password will be changed, But I need to same password.

Tried solutions:

1. I put the variables into the `test.describe` block.
2. I put the variables into the `beforeEach` block.

I did all of these and always the value of the variable changed.

Comment: Did you try a `beforeAll` block?

Answer (score 1):

You can [set a seed](https://fakerjs.dev/guide/usage.html#reproducible-results) when creating values and set it in each test to get the same values, like this:

```
faker.seed(12345); // initial seed
const email = faker.internet.email();
const password = faker.internet.password();
const newPassword = faker.internet.password();
const simplePassword = faker.internet.password();

test.describe('Signup a new user', async ({ page }) => {
  test('Signup a new user', async ({page}) => {
    faker.seed(12345);
    await SignUp.EnterEmail(email);
    await SignUp.EnterPassword(password);
  
  }
  
  test('Try to change password with a valid new password', async ({page}) => {
    faker.seed(12345); // setting seed here will reproduce the same value
    await Profile.typeCurrentPassword(password)
    await Profile.typeNewPassword(newPassword);
    await Profile.confirmPassword(newPassword);
    await Profile.save();
  
  }
  
  test('// Try to change password with simple password', async ({page}) => {
    faker.seed(12345);
    await Profile.typeCurrentPassword(password)
    await Profile.typeNewPassword(simplePassword);
    await Profile.confirmPassword(simplePassword);
    await Profile.save();
  
  }

}
```